# s3 and dynamo configuration not working for Loki

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, grafana-loki

I have configured Loki to save data in s3 and indexes in dynamodb Like
https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/fb318152fe28486640668563548b125c00c7f52b/docs/aws_storage.md

But the pod is failing to start with error

```
level=error ts=2020-06-29T13:04:33.086757753Z caller=table_manager.go:176 msg="error syncing tables" err="InvalidEndpointURL: invalid endpoint uri\ncaused by: parse https://dynamodb.A****A:0.amazonaws.com/: invalid port \":0.amazonaws.com\" after host"
```

So the current configuration is

```
config:
  table_manager:
    retention_deletes_enabled: true
  schema_config:
    configs:
    - from: 2020-01-01
      store: aws
      object_store: aws
      schema: v9
      index:
        prefix: loki_index
        period: 0
  storage_config:
    aws: 
      s3: s3://A***A:0/u***K@eu-west-1/xms-loki-master
      dynamodbconfig:
        dynamodb: dynamodb://A***A:0/u***K@eu-west-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.
You're probably hitting the problem where you have either '/' or '0/' in you access key.
Two solutions: either regenerate a new access key and make sure it has no slashes in it, or url encode the key (replacing / with `%2F`) as suggested here:
https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/1607